# TypeError: Callback is already a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a bot and I need help with something! I'm getting that error when I try to execute the script

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 56, in <module>
        async def rob(ctx,member:discord.Member):
      File "/home/runner/Iron-Hub/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1262, in decorator
        result = command(*args, **kwargs)(func)
      File "/home/runner/Iron-Hub/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1432, in decorator
        raise TypeError('Callback is already a command.')
    TypeError: Callback is already a command.
```

the code is

```py
 import discord from discord.ext import commands import os import json
 from discord_slash import SlashCommand import random from
 discord.ext.commands import BucketType from discord.ext.commands
 import cooldown
 
 ##define como chamar o bot client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!",case_insensitive = True) slash = SlashCommand(client,
 sync_commands=True) client.remove_command("help")
 
 ##mandando uma msg quando o bot estiver online @client.event async def on_ready():   print ("estamos online")   
 ##definindo comandos slash @slash.slash(name="Olá", description="fala oi pro bot") async def ola(ctx):
     await ctx.send(f"Olá,{ctx.author}")
 
 #sistema de help    @client.group(invoke_without_command=True) async def help(ctx):
     em = discord.Embed(title = "Help", description = "use !help para lista de  comandos.",color = ctx.author.color)
 
     em.add_field(name = "moderation", value = "kick,ban,warn")
     em.add_field(name = "economia", value ="esmola,dinheiro,trabalhar")
 
     await ctx.send(embed = em)
 
 
 @client.command() async def Dinheiro(ctx):
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     user = ctx.author
     users = await get_bank_data()
 
     wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
     bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
     pet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["pets"]
     em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s Balance",color = discord.Color.red())
     em.add_field(name = "Carteira",value = wallet_amt)
     em.add_field(name = "Banco",value = bank_amt)
     em.add_field(name = "Pets",value = pet_amt)
     await ctx.send(embed = em)
 
 @client.command()
 
 @client.command() async def rob(ctx,member:discord.Member):
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     await open_account(member)
 
     if amount == None:
         await ctx.send("porfavor insira um valor")
         return

    bal = await update_bank(member)

    amount = int(amount)
    if bal[0]<100:
        await ctx.send("e inutil roubar ele nao tem dinheiro")
        return

    earnings = random.randrange(0, bal[0])

 
   await update_bank(ctx.author,earnings)
    await update_bank(member,-1* earnings)

    await ctx.send(f"Você roubor de e conseguiu {amount} dinheiros")


async def enviar(ctx,member:discord.Member,amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)
  
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Por Favor Escreva Um valor")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[1]:
        await ctx.send("você não tem esse dinheiro")
        return
    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send("A quantia tem quer ser positiva")
        return

    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount,"bank")
    await update_bank(member,amount,"bank")

    await ctx.send(f"Você enviou {amount} dinheiros!") @client.command() async def apostar_roleta(ctx,amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Porfavor digite um valor")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[0]:
        await ctx.send("Você não tem esse dinheiro")
        return
      
    final = []
    for i in range(3):
        a = random.choice(["X","O","Q"])

        final.append(a)

    await ctx.send(str(final))

    if final[0] == final[1] or final[0] == final[2] or final[2] == final[1]:
    
    await update_bank(ctx.author,2*amount)
         await ctx.send("Você ganhou")
     else:
         await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount)
         await ctx.send("Você perdeu") async def open_account(user):
 
     users = await get_bank_data()
 
     if str(user.id) in users:
       return False    @client.command() async def Depositar(ctx,amount = None):
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     if amount == None:
         await ctx.send("Por Favor Escreva Um valor")
         return
 
     bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
     amount = int(amount)
     if amount>bal[0]:
         await ctx.send("você não tem esse dinheiro")
         return
     if amount <0:
         await ctx.send("A quantia tem quer ser positiva")
         return
 
     await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount)
     await update_bank(ctx.author,amount,"bank")
 
     await ctx.send(f"Você depositou {amount} de dinheiros!")
 
 @client.command() async def Sacar(ctx,amount = None):
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     if amount == None:
         await ctx.send("Por Favor Escreva Um valor")
         return
 
     bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
     amount = int(amount)
     if amount>bal[1]:
         await ctx.send("você não tem esse dinheiro")
         return
     if amount <0:
         await ctx.send("A quantia tem quer ser positiva")
         return
 
     await update_bank(ctx.author,amount)
     await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount,"bank")
 
     await ctx.send(f"Você sacou {amount} de dinheiros!") @client.event async def on_command_error(ctx, error):   if isinstance(error,
 commands.CommandOnCooldown):
       msg = '**Ainda em cooldown**, tente novamente em {:.2f}s'.format(error.retry_after)
       await ctx.send(msg)
        @client.command() @cooldown(1,240, BucketType.user) async def Trabalhar(ctx):
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     user = ctx.author
     users = await get_bank_data()
 
     quantia = (100)
     pet = users[str(user.id)]["pets"]
     pet_valor = pet * 2
     earnings = quantia + pet_valor
 
     await ctx.send(f"você trabalhou e ganhou {earnings} dinheiros!")
   
     users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
 
     with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
         json.dump(users,f)
       
 
 @client.command() @cooldown(1,240, BucketType.user) async def
 Esmola(ctx):
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     user = ctx.author
     users = await get_bank_data()
 
     quantia = random.randrange(150)
     pet = users[str(user.id)]["pets"]
     pet_valor = pet * 2
     earnings = quantia + pet_valor
     
     await ctx.send(f"Alguem te deu {earnings} dinheiros!")
   
     users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
 
     with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
         json.dump(users,f)
 
 async def open_account(user):
 
     users = await get_bank_data()
 
     if str(user.id) in users:
         return False
     else:
         users[str(user.id)] = {}
         users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
         users[str(user.id)] ["bank"] = 0
         users[str(user.id)] ["pets"] = 0
         users[str(user.id)] ["nitro"] = 0
         users[str(user.id)] ["vip"] = 0
 
     with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
         json.dump(users,f)
     return True
 
 
 async def get_bank_data():
     with open ("mainbank.json","r") as f:
         users = json.load(f)
 
     return users
      
 ##definindo key do bot async def update_bank(user,change = 0, mode = wallet"):
     users = await get_bank_data()
 
     users[str(user.id)][mode] += change
 
     with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
         json.dump(users,f)
 
 
     bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"], users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]  
     return bal
```

if someone help me with that would be nice

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `@client.command()` decorator. Remove it.

[image]